# Best way to photograph a sunset

Tags: sunset

What are the best settings to photograph a sunset ?

Answer (score 1):

A *variety* of settings! You might want to try under-exposing to emphasize cloud colors, or exposing for detail in shadowed areas, or try high-dynamic-range (HDR) through bracketing and post-processing.

See what you (or your critics ;-) like: *De gustibus non est disputandum.*

Comment: Do you use HDR as an effect or you shot different exposures than you merge them together?

Comment: Some cameras have HDR "built in", but you can perform the same effect manually: take a few photos of the same scene, carefully aligned, and use software to merge them, e.g. Picturenaut, http://www.hdrlabs.com/picturenaut/